# Umbraco switching to https and calling a code behind event on login

Tags: https, code-behind, umbraco

Have the below code to switch requests from ‘http’ to ‘https’ when user clicks on a button. This is to protect user/password info before it is sent to the server. In the server, should call the code behind associated to the button but is not doing it. On pages that are NOT under Umbraco this code works fine.

Control:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnLogin" runat="server" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" ... />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PostBackOptions pbOptions = new PostBackOptions(btnLogin);
    pbOptions.ActionUrl = Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http://", "https://");
    btnLogin.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled = true; + Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(pbOptions) + ";");
}

protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
   want to execute that code
}
```

If put this code in an Umbraco page, when click on the login button the request changes to ‘https’, page is post to the server but the btnLogin_Click event is NOT called.

Is there something need to change to make this work in Umbraco? Does anybody know a solution / work around to make ‘btnLogin_Click’ to be executed? Or any idea where I can look to find the problem?

Thanks

Comment: The 'WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions' does not seem to work in Umbraco. To do the 'http' to 'https' change had to trick the call changing 'theForm.action' to https.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding in your Page_Load:

```
btnLogin_Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(btnLogin_Click);
```

You may need to add this, as unless you have AutoEventWireup="true" specified in your usercontrol/masterpage declaration, it won't be automatically fired on postback.

HTH,

Benjamin

Comment: Yes, the AutoEventWireup="true" was there but Umbraco is a world apart, full of problems. Anyway, as I said found a workaround. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Riga, could you post your workaround for future reference to other users struggling with similar problems? Thanks.